# Open URL with a set Target

Tags: url, batch-file, browser, target

**EDIT:** 
The solution I am seeking is a command line to be run to accomplish this from a batch file in Windows.

---

How would I mimic a browser function to open a URL with a specific target so that if that tab is already open it will load there instead of creating a new tab?

So instead of the default http://url.com with the target "_blank", I could change this to "w00t", etc.

I am using Chrome exclusively, so if this were to be a Chrome specific command, that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a HTML-page and add the following code like this:

```
<script>
  var url = getQueryVariable("url");
  var target = getQueryVariable("target");
  window.open(url,target);

  function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if (pair[0] == variable) {
        return pair[1];
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have this script hosted here: [scriptcoded.github.io/redirect](http://scriptcoded.github.io/redirect)

You could then call it from a batch-file using this command:

```
START scriptcoded.github.io/redirect?url=http://www.google.com&target=w00t
```

Use `?url=http://www.google.com&target=_blank` to set the redirect.

The only problems I find with this method is that some browsers blocks the new window and that the tab won't close. Yes, we could use `window.close();`, but it will only close tabs that were opened by the webpage itself.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's a very good solution, that will definitely work the best if there isn't a built in way to do this with pure batch, but since I don't need it to be, this is great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

set name for html tag of target page like this:

```
<html name="w00t">
```

Note: A link to URL with target name, sets the name for target window automatically:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="w00t">Google</a>
```

Comment: And how would I do this as a batch command line for a web page I do not own, such as YouTube?

Comment: When you set target attribute for a link, it is automatically set as name of new opened window and acts as you desire.

Comment: I'm not sure I worded my question correctly then. I want a batch command (or commands) that open the URL I give it with a specified target that I can also give it